Why can't the token pasting operator (##) be used to concatenate two strings?
Why can't the token pasting operator be used to concatenate two strings?
For example;
#include <stdio.h>
#define  MESSAGE "hello"##"world" 

int main() {
printf(MESSAGE);
}

error: pasting ""hello"" and ""world"" does not give a valid preprocessing token

There's no need, such concatenation is already built-in: "hello" "world" would create the single string constant "helloworld".

Thank's a lot. okey, I know this. I just need why we error occours when using ## and string literals.

From this reference: "A ## operator between any two successive identifiers in the replacement-list runs parameter replacement on the two identifiers and then concatenates the result." (emphasis mine). And also: "Only tokens that form a valid token together may be pasted: identifiers that form a longer identifier, digits that form a number, or operators + and = that form a +=."

Because "hello""wolrd" is not a valid preprocessing token. A single string literal is.

From my linked reference above, and to expand on the comment by @EugeneSh., it's then easy to see that "hello" ## "world" would create "hello""world" and not a single string "helloworld". It's just not what the token-pasting operator is doing.

Also, while it haven't been true in compilers for a long time, I think it's better to look at the preprocessor as a standalone program which does its own separate pass over the source, before the actual compiler get to it. And that the preprocessor is its own language that is separate and distinct from C (or C++), that doesn't know anything about strings or numbers or anything like that. This way of looking at it also makes it easier to understand the concept of translation units.

I think I understand that the preprocessor gives an error when trying to make a single atom because there are still 2 atoms. Alright
How does the preprocessor understand that the expression "hello" "world" consists of 2 atoms?

The preprocessor and its language is really simple, and more importantly text-based. All operations it does are really on text. A macro does text substitution. An #include does text insertion. And the contatenation operator takes two texts and appends them to form a single new text. A ## B results in AB, verbatim. It doesn't really matter what A and B might be. You could do "hello" ## hello and get "hello"hello.

hi again, thank's a a lot. I know, the peprocessor's language very simple. "hello" ## "hello" ifadesi means "hello""hello". It's okey. But why am i seeing this error? The Error: pasting ""hello"" and ""world"" does not give a valid preprocessing token

In that particular error message, the outer quotes are added by the compiler for the purpose of the error message only.  Inside are the tokens you are trying to paste.  The inner quotes are literal characters from those two tokens, "hello" and "world".  Again, the preprocessor just manipulates pieces of text. It does categorize them, but it doesn't have much sense of what they mean to C, outside the scope of the preprocessor.  And again, pasting those two tokens together is not allowed in the first place because they are not identifiers, and would not produce a valid token anyway.

@Someprogrammerdude Ever since C89, the preprocessor operates on pp-tokens, not text. You can't properly understand all the corner cases of the preprocessor's behavior (arguably including the one the question is about!) if you pretend it operates on text.

Pasting 2 string literals is invalid because it does not form a valid single token. Note however that there is no need to use ## in this case as merely juxtaposing two (or more) string literals is legal and parsed as a single string.

You don't need to paste two string literals, as when they appear in the source, they are merged together.
printf("Hello " 
       "world\n");

simply works!!!!

As noted, ## concatenates preprocessor tokens, not strings. The standard just says that if the result of ## is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.
And there's no need need to concatenate string literals since that happens anyway, in the next translation phase after macro replacement. But before everything is converted to "regular" tokens and syntax parsed. Meaning "hello" "world" is equivalent to "helloworld" and code like printf("%c","hello" "world"[5]); is guaranteed to print w.
In case you need to work with string concatenation in the pre-processor stage, then concatenate pp-tokens first and then "stringinize" them after:
#define STR(s) #s
#define MESSAGE STR(hello##world)

The preprocessor works so that it resolves ## and # in each macro before it replaces macros, so this will result in helloworld (after ##), then "helloworld" (after #) and hello & world need not even be #defined macros.
